# Property of convergent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum a(n)$ and $\sum b(n)$ are convergent series with positive terms,can I say that $\sum a(n)b(n)$ is also convergent?

Comment: Since $\sum_n |a_n| < \infty$, it suffices that $b(n)$ is bounded to obtain $\sum_n |a_n b_n| < \infty$, no need that $b(n) \to 0$ or $\sum_n b(n) < \infty$.

Comment: Yes, you can.${}{}{}{}{}$